# Automatic authentication in group of wifi peer-2-peer (wifi direct)

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifimanager, wifip2p

I want to make the connection process of a group in WiFi peer-2-peer seamless for the users.
Is there a way to do that ?

How is it done in Bluetooth?

Comment: Do you want to make it like bluetooth where user click on OK button only like in bluetooth where you have to just click on Pair and not even enter the PIN.

Comment: Today the dialog in wifi-direct has a ok button.
I want all the connection/re-connection process to be unnoticed by the user.
the user will see a dynamic network being built has device gets next to him or away from him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically there would be two ways on doing this, and I'm discussing the ways in [WIFI DIRECT, CONNECTIONS WITHOUT USER INTERACTION](http://www.drjukka.com/blog/wordpress/?p=39) blog article

You could check my [Thaili/WAPConApp](https://github.com/thaliproject/WAPConApp) library example on how the accesspoint approach would work. and Wifi Pairing is discussed in [other blog article](http://www.drjukka.com/blog/wordpress/?p=46).

Comment: Your way let me become a legacy node of the GO but I want a connection between 2 wifi direct peers in a normal mode (not legacy). Do you think there is a way to do this ?

Comment: You could try the pairing thing, though I have seen some strange behaviour with it, thus I'm now not 100% certain it would work always right. But if you are looking for fully automatic way, then I have not seen anything for it.